# Applications cannot access settings

Tags: windows-10

I was just playing a videogame when a popup appeared, telling me that there is not much space left on C:. I closed it and continued to play. Later I took a break of about an hour. When I came back and opened up the game again, it was as if I opened it the first time. All the settings were lost (graphics settings, game progress, etc). I restarted my PC, however it didn't help.

The thing is that there is not only a single application which cannot access its settings. I tried two more games, and they also lost their settings. However, the correct settings-files with the **correct** content still exist in the AppData-folder, so they have not been deleted.

It seems like the applications cannot access the settings-files. How can that be and how can I fix it?

Comment: Running out of disc space is generally disastrous, whatever the OS. Most applications need to create temporary files while they are running: if they can't, they will fail in unpredictable ways. Further, if you have only one drive, then your swap space (`pagefile.sys`) will be on it, and if this runs out you will be unable to get programs into memory, even to stop themselves in order to release memory. The only solution is to increase the available disc space, either by increasing the disc size through compression or replacement, or by removing little-used files and applications.